# Multiple Data Contexts in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core-2.0

In my ASP.NET Core 2 MVC project, I am trying to add a second data context "FacilityClaimContext" to my controller. Everything was fine up to this point.  I am getting error message:

"*InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'FacilityClaimApplication.Models.FacilityClaimContext' while attempting to activate 'FacilityClaimApplication.Controllers.FacilitiesController'.*"

**FacilitiesController.cs**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class FacilitiesController : Controller
{
    private readonly CQO1Context _context;
    private readonly FacilityClaimContext _facClaimContext;

    public FacilitiesController(CQO1Context context, FacilityClaimContext cfcontext)
    {
        _context = context;
        _facClaimContext = cfcontext;
    }
```

...
    }

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
            .AddDbContext<CQO1Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Cqo1Connection")));           

        ... }
```

**FacilityClaimContext.cs**

```
namespace FacilityClaimApplication.Models
{
public partial class FacilityClaimContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ClaimedFacilities> ClaimedFacilities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ClaimedFacilityListingDetails> ClaimedFacilityListingDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ClaimedFacilityListingImages> ClaimedFacilityListingImages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ClaimedFacilityOwners> ClaimedFacilityOwners { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ClaimedFacilityUserAssociation> ClaimedFacilityUserAssociation { get; set; }

... }
```

**Appsettings.json**

```
  {  "ConnectionStrings": {
"Cqo1Connection": "Server=xxx;Database=CQO1;User=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"DefaultConnection": "Server=xxx;Database=FacilityClaim;User=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
 } }
```

ASP.NET Core 2 is new to me, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: your startup seems to be registering ApplicationDbContext, but your controller is expecting a FacilityClaimContext.  Where is FacilityClaimContext registered with your container?

Comment: Your comment assisted me in fixing the issue.